# Using a parent/child self join in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to make a parent/child has_many/belongs_to relationship work in rails. This seems a bit trickier than more typical models. I'm new to Rails so forgive me if this seems like a very simple question.
This is my model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :subcategories,   class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent,          class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

And this is the way that seems like would be the proper way to create the objects:

```
parent = Category.new(name: 'animal')
child = parent.subcategories.build(name: 'cat')

parent.subcategories #this works fine
child.parent #this returns nil
```

The only way I've found that works is to add `child.parent = parent` but this doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

EDIT:

This is the rspec test I'm using and the output

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Category, type: :model do
  context "Category" do
    before(:all) do
      @parent = Category.new(name: 'animal')
      @child = @parent.subcategories.build(name: 'cat')
    end

    it "should equal subcategory" do
      expect(@parent.subcategories.first).to eq(@child)
    end
    it "should reference to parent" do
      expect(@child.parent).to eq(@parent)
    end
  end
end
```

And the result

```
21:44:56 - INFO - Running: spec/models/category_spec.rb
.F

Failures:

  1) Category Category should reference to parent
     Failure/Error: expect(@child.parent).to eq(@parent)

       expected: #<Category id: nil, name: "animal", parent_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02808 seconds (files took 3.48 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:13 # Category Category should reference to parent
```

Comment: Here are the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. I'm a bit confused about `#build`. You might have to persist the parent category first for `child.parent` to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a few (ok a bunch) of hours of searching through ActiveRecord here is what I found.

Assuming this:

```
class create_category_table < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.integer :parent_id
    end
  end
end 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories, class: Category, foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, class: Category
end

@parent = Category.new
@child  = @parent.sub_categories.build
```

Basically the reason that `@child.parent` returns `nil` is because when the new record is added to `@parent.sub_categories` via the `#build` method, active record has no way of knowing what the inverse relationship of the has_many association is.  This is because we give them names, "sub_categories" and "parent", which cannot be derived by active record from the class name.  Active record lets you add a `:class` and `:foreign_key` option to clarify which class to use when instantiating related objects and which foreign_key to look up when finding a record. BUT it specifically does not create an inverse reflection for the relationship (which the association looks up when adding a record in `#build`) because `:foreign_key` is in the array of `INVALID_AUTOMATIC_INVERSE_OPTIONS`.

There is a bit more to it than all this, but from this exploration, I have discovered a very simple solution, and that is to explicitly declare the inverse name for a reflection.

Adding this code underneath the associations, will allow you to look up both `@parent.sub_categories` and `@child.parent` **WITHOUT** *persisting any records in the database*:

```
reflections["sub_categories"].options[:inverse_of] = :parent
reflections["parent"].options[:inverse_of] = :sub_categories
```

OR (and I really hope I didn't waste a lot of time on this), simply add an `:inverse_of` option to the association options:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories, class: Category, foreign_key: :parent_id, inverse_of: :parent
  belongs_to :parent, class: Category, inverse_of: :sub_categories
end
```

Aaaaaaaaaaaaannd after discovering all that, here are the docs that it is clearly explained in: (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

...

Comment: This is why stackoverflow is great! This seems like a very good approach to me. I notice that using `inverse_of:` by itself seemed to have no effect for me, but setting the reflections options instead works.

Comment: Really? Thats interesting. What version of active record are you using?

Comment: Ok. That's wierd. That's what I was testing with.

Comment: Oh, using `inverse_of:` does work, I didn't notice that you also added it to the has_many statement before. That's what I get for not slowly reading everything carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that your parent hasn't been saved yet. Change this:

```
@parent = Category.new(name: 'animal')
```

to the following:

```
@parent = Category.create(name: 'animal')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That was the problem, the test passes now.

Comment: Just to note, this seems to be a bug (or at least inconsistency) in ActiveRecord.  This occurs in has_many / belongs_to  where you have to specify a class or a foreign_key.  This works: `class Category < ActiveRecord::Base; has_many :categories; belongs_to :category; end`, but this (`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base; has_many :cats, class: Category; belongs_to :cat, class: Category; end`) or this (`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base; has_many :categories, foreign_key: :parent_id; belongs_to :category, foreign_key: :parent_id; end`) will give you `nil` for `child.parent`.

Answer (score 1):

The `belongs_to` relation does not need a `foreign_key` attribute. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Comment: That's right, but even without it, the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious `build` is a `ActiveRecord association` method. So it eventually keep associations during build. But `new` object doesn't have any idea of associations. So it reflecting a `nil`.

Your join things are perfect.